# OpenSSL -aes-256-cbc decryption behavior changed between 1.0.2o and 1.1.0g

Tags: openssl

This works with OpenSSL 1.0.2o:

```
$ echo s+pQpLgAQKY6z9fNtBz63A== | openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -k a -nosalt
foobar
```

The same command doesn't work with OpenSSL 1.1.0g:

```
bad decrypt
140479496508672:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:536:
```

Is there a command-line which works with both versions? If not, is there a command-line flag which I can add for OpenSSL 1.1.0g to make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `-md md5` to the command makes it work in both versions (1.0.2o and 1.1.0g).

Comment: Yes. The official OpenSSL FAQ entry on this is here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER3

Comment: How to specify this in the C API?